# Azure ARM Template - List resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible and if yes how, to list available (previously created) VMs, so that I can select my "target" from dropdown during the deployment process from my ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

no, this is not possible, you have to use other means (powershell\cli\rest api\sdk) to find that information and pass it to the template.

if your VM list never changes - you can hardcode it as `allowedValues` for the parameter. that will achieve what you want, but you'll have to update those everytime you create\delete\move vm.

Comment: Hm, so it's possible to run powershell commands within the template to dynamically populate dropdown for example with allowed values for options?

Comment: no, it is not, you have to preprocess that and use something like `get-azvm | out-gridview -passthru` for the user to pick the vm and then pass it to the `new-azresourcegroupdeployment`